# MS Word: Printing: Starting each new 'section' on a new sheet when printing on both sides

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

How do I print a MS Word document so that when printing on both sides each new 'section' is started on a new sheet of paper?
I suppose the 'sections' can be separated with a page break or some similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention: Page Layout, Page Setup, Breaks, Odd Page.